# RMI marshal and serialization

Tags: java, object, serialization, marshalling, rmi

In java using RMI to marshal an object that you are returning from the remote class do you just need to implement Serializable on that object? I have a class node with variables inside that i want to be returned. Do i just implement serializable? If so what about the class that is receiving the object? does its class need to implement serializable too?

example:

```
public class node implements Serializable{
//variables
//variables
public node(//arguments to constructor here){

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The class that is being serialized needs to implement Serializable. The sending and receiving classes don't. Not sure why you would think otherwise.

Comment: what if we are calling a remote method and passing an argument(for example just a string), does it have to be serializable or should it? Do only objects have to be serializable?

Comment: Arguments and results of remote methods need to be serializable, as do any non-static non-transient members, and so on recursively until closure.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a class whose instances you want to serialize using built-in Java serialization, not only must it implement `Serializable`, all its instance variables must also implement `Serializable`, or be primitives, or be marked `transient` (i.e. you tell the JVM that it's okay for them to not get serialized).

If your class can't conform to these constraints for some reason, you can implement custom serialization behavior yourself by implementing `Externalizable` - then you take responsibility for writing out your object's state and reading it back on the other end.

Comment: so to do this i just make the class implement serializable or is there more to this? Or does every variables in the class need to have some specific extention to it that i don't know about

Comment: The class needs to implement `Serializable`.  Any fields on the class you want serialized should also implement `Serializable`, or be primitives.  "Specific extension?" Not sure I understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether I understand your question correctly or not, but ... if the serializable class has other objects as member variables, then better make them serializable also, otherwise better declare as transient to skip.  does this answer your question?

if code inspector program is handy, you can have answer for such question very quickly without posting it

for your tip, only the object you wan to persist or transfer needs to implements Serializable, so the object can be reconstructed as the class structure through serializing/unserializing